# Rails PUT with nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have `Post` and `Comment` models like below in my Rails 5.1 API app

**Post**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :comments
end
```

**Comment**

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :post
end
```

**Post Serializer (uses ActiveModel Seriazlier) **

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :text, :created_at

  has_many :comments
end
```

When a user visits `/posts/:id` and adds a comment to a post via the front-end app ( Angular 2) , I'm calling `PUT /posts:id` with the `post` object nested with the existing `comments` and the new comment.

How do I handle this in `post_controller.rb` such that the  new `comment` is inserted to the database with the right dish association ?

my `post#update` method is as follows

```
  # PATCH/PUT /post/1
  def update
    if @post.update(post_params)
      render json: @post
    else
      render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

**Update:**

I'm adding the `Post` model from my Angular 2 client side. The `Post` model has `Comment[]` as one of the members. When a new comment is added via the form the `comment` is push to `post.comments` array before sending the whole object to the Rails API back-end.

**`Post` model in client side**

```
import { Comment } from './comment';

export class Post {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  text: string;
  date: string;
  comments: Comment[];
}
```

**`Comment` model in client side**

```
export class Comment {
    comment: string;
    date: string;
}
```

Comment: show your post form

Comment: the form in `/post/:id` is for users to input the comments. I have added both the `Post` and `Comment` model from Angular 2 client side - hope this covers it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `accepts_nested_attributes_for` comments from Post model. If you pass comments attributes as nested attributes without id parameter, new records will be created. And if you pass it with existing id, the existing record will be updated accordingly.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end
```

And the post params should permit the nested attributes

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:id, :title, ... , 
    comments_attributes: [:id, :comment] # Provide comment model attributes here]
  )
end
```

Rails has a good documentation for this [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: I tired this approach - but new comment still do not get saved. Posted `rails server` console logs here - https://pastebin.com/F1C65c4k

Comment: you may look at this question which has more details - https://stackoverflow.com/q/47249461/3206440