# PUT with nested object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular

I have `Dish` and `Comment` models like below in my Rails 5.1 API app - code repo [here](https://github.com/webapps07/conrailsAPI) . I need help with adding a  new `Comment` to a `Dish`.

**Post**

```
class Dish < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :comments
end
```

**Comment**

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :dish
end
```

**Post Serializer (uses ActiveModel Seriazlier)**

```
class DishSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :image, :category, :label, :price, :featured, :description, :created_at

  has_many :comments
end
```

**Comment Serializer**

```
class CommentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :rating, :comment, :author, :date

  def date
    object.created_at
  end
end
```

**Post Controller** - default rails scaffold

```
class DishesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_dish, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /dishes
  def index
    @dishes = Dish.all

    render json: @dishes
  end

  # GET /dishes/1
  def show
    render json: @dish
  end

  # POST /dishes
  def create
    @dish = Dish.new(dish_params)

    if @dish.save
      render json: @dish, status: :created, location: @dish
    else
      render json: @dish.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /dishes/1
  def update
    # byebug
    if @dish.update(dish_params)
      render json: @dish
    else
      render json: @dish.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /dishes/1
  def destroy
    @dish.destroy
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_dish
      @dish = Dish.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def dish_params
      params.require(:dish).permit(:name, :image, :category, :label, :price, :featured, :description)
    end
end
```

**Comment Controller** - default rails scaffold

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /comments
  def index
    @comments = Comment.all

    render json: @comments
  end

  # GET /comments/1
  def show
    render json: @comment
  end

  # POST /comments
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)

    if @comment.save
      render json: @comment, status: :created, location: @comment
    else
      render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /comments/1
  def update
    if @comment.update(comment_params)
      render json: @comment
    else
      render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /comments/1
  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_comment
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:rating, :comment, :author)
    end
end
```

**Issue**

When a user visits `/dishes/:id` and adds a comment to a dish via the front-end app ( Angular 2) , the `comment` is push to the array of current comments and I'm calling `PUT /dishes:id` with the `dish` object nested with the existing `comments` and the new comment. However the new `comment` is not saved by rails - no error returned, rather the `dish` object is returned. However I do see `Unpermitted parameters: :id, :created_at` in `rails s` console. How do I get rails to save the new comment ?

The page ( `dishes/9` ) from where I'm adding the comment to a dish looks like below on the Angular client side.
[image]

**Rails Server logs**

On the rails side, below is what I see in `params` - I do see the new comment - `{"author"=>"JANE7777", "rating"=>3, "comment"=>"COMMENT7777", "date"=>"2017-11-12T12:58:12.555Z"}` in there.

```
Started PUT "/dishes/9" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-12 18:28:12 +0530
Processing by DishesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"9", "name"=>"Uthappizza", "image"=>"images/uthappizza.png", "category"=>"mains", "label"=>"Hot", "price"=>"4.99", "featured"=>true, "description"=>"A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.", "created_at"=>"2017-11-01T04:30:09.407Z", "comments"=>[{"id"=>46, "rating"=>5, "comment"=>"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!", "author"=>"John Lemon", "date"=>"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556Z"}, {"id"=>47, "rating"=>4, "comment"=>"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!", "author"=>"Paul McVites", "date"=>"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556Z"}, {"id"=>48, "rating"=>3, "comment"=>"Eat it, just eat it!", "author"=>"Michael Jaikishan", "date"=>"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556Z"}, {"id"=>49, "rating"=>4, "comment"=>"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!", "author"=>"Ringo Starry", "date"=>"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556Z"}, {"id"=>50, "rating"=>2, "comment"=>"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!", "author"=>"25 Cent", "date"=>"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556Z"}, {"id"=>51, "rating"=>4, "comment"=>"great dish", "author"=>"Jogesh", "date"=>"2017-10-30T05:03:39.656Z"}, {"author"=>"JANE7777", "rating"=>3, "comment"=>"COMMENT7777", "date"=>"2017-11-12T12:58:12.555Z"}], "dish"=>{"id"=>"9", "name"=>"Uthappizza", "image"=>"images/uthappizza.png", "category"=>"mains", "label"=>"Hot", "price"=>"4.99", "featured"=>true, "description"=>"A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.", "created_at"=>"2017-11-01T04:30:09.407Z"}}
  Dish Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "dishes".* FROM "dishes" WHERE "dishes"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]

[25, 34] in C:/apps/railsApi/app/controllers/dishes_controller.rb
   25:   end
   26:
   27:   # PATCH/PUT /dishes/1
   28:   def update
   29:     byebug
=> 30:     if @dish.update(dish_params)
   31:       render json: @dish
   32:     else
   33:       render json: @dish.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
   34:     end
(byebug) params
<ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>"9", "name"=>"Uthappizza", "image"=>"images/uthappizza.png", "category"=>"mains", "label"=>"Hot", "price"=>"4.99", "featured"=>true, "description"=>"A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.", "created_at"=>"2017-11-01T04:30:09.407Z", "comments"=>[{"id"=>46, "rating"=>5, "comment"=>"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!", "author"=>"John Lemon", "date"=>"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556Z"}, {"id"=>47, "rating"=>4, "comment"=>"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!", "author"=>"Paul McVites", "date"=>"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556Z"}, {"id"=>48, "rating"=>3, "comment"=>"Eat it, just eat it!", "author"=>"Michael Jaikishan", "date"=>"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556Z"}, {"id"=>49, "rating"=>4, "comment"=>"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!", "author"=>"Ringo Starry", "date"=>"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556Z"}, {"id"=>50, "rating"=>2, "comment"=>"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!", "author"=>"25 Cent", "date"=>"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556Z"}, {"id"=>51, "rating"=>4, "comment"=>"great dish", "author"=>"Jogesh", "date"=>"2017-10-30T05:03:39.656Z"}, {"author"=>"JANE7777", "rating"=>3, "comment"=>"COMMENT7777", "date"=>"2017-11-12T12:58:12.555Z"}], "controller"=>"dishes", "action"=>"update", "dish"=>{"id"=>9, "name"=>"Uthappizza", "image"=>"images/uthappizza.png", "category"=>"mains", "label"=>"Hot", "price"=>"4.99", "featured"=>true, "description"=>"A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.", "created_at"=>"2017-11-01T04:30:09.407Z"}} permitted: false>
(byebug) c
Unpermitted parameters: :id, :created_at
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
   (0.0ms)  COMMIT
[active_model_serializers]   Comment Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."dish_id" = $1  [["dish_id", 9]]
[active_model_serializers] Rendered DishSerializer with ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::Attributes (31.29ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1901725ms (Views: 37.5ms | ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)
```

**Client-side models**

The `Dish` model has `Comment[]` as one of the members. When a new comment is added via the form the `comment` is push to `dish.comments` array before sending the `Dish` object to the Rails API back-end.

**`Comment` model in client side**

```
export class Comment {
    rating: number;
    comment: string;
    author: string;
    date: string;
}
```

**`Post` model in client side**

```
import { Comment } from './comment';
export class Dish {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  image: string;
  category: string;
  label: string;
  price: string;
  featured: boolean;
  description: string;
  comments: Comment[];
}
```

Comment: did you check CSRF issues and the error it shows related to unpermitted params?

PUT is for updating , POST is for creating. You can try using a nested resource or if you want to continue using push add accepts_nested_attributes for in dish.rb for comment.rb . 

Try to write a small test case instead of retrying or testing from the UI to help understand or run the code in the byebug console.

Comment: I use `rack-cors` and have configured - my GET requests work well !!

Comment: Why don't you make a separate action comments#create? Your solution is hacky. Even if it gonna work, it's not something you should really looking for.

Comment: There is `create` method in `CommentsController` - I just added it here.

Comment: But you don't mention any of it's usage when you add new comment. Have you tried to go with accepts_nested_attributes?

Comment: Yes, I did try `accepts_nested_attributes: comments` in `Dish` model - it did not create the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I’d recommend you use the Comments controller and form a nested route to be RESTful.

Firstly, POST the request, including the dish_id to /comments. You’re trying to create a Comment, not update the Dish.

Secondly, form the nested route:
/dishes/:dish_id/comments

Here’s a guide to nesting resources like this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

The reason for your error is that you’ve broken the expected parameter structure. For a PUT your params should be:

```
{
   id: <record to update>,
   dish: {
      name: “blah”,
      comments: [{...},{...}]
   }
 }
```

Again, I really recommend you don’t PUT to Dish if you just want to add a Comment. For instance: the above would be desired to replace all comments on the Dish! If you’re creating a record, create that record, don’t update it’s parent.

If you wanted to update the Dish when a new Comment is added you can add a callback to the Comment model on create or do it in the Comment create controller action.